# Elasticsearch (ELK stack) division of sum of fields

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any possible way on doing below operation on `Elasticsearch`

`Sum(field1) / Sum(field2)`

Also is tgere any opensource project like PowerBi.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use script:

"script": "doc['param1'].value != 0 ? doc['param2'].value / doc['param1'].value : 0"